# Error 1064 in Grafana for making a graph using mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, grafana

I am using Grafana to make a graph of my data. I have 4 columns. The Time(using variable f), 2 sensor variables (int1 and int2) and ID.

But I receive the error:

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'int1
>   FROM data5
>   WHERE
>     f BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1563773333) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(15' at line 3

This is the generated code:

```sql
    SELECT
       f AS "time",
       int1
    FROM data5
    WHERE
       f BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1563775600) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1563797200)
    ORDER BY f
```

Comment: can you post your database structure..

Comment: `FROM_UNIXTIME` returns string, compare dates instead of strings

Answer (score 0):

```
select created_at as time,id 
from table 
where created_at between FROM_UNIXTIME(1542196778) and FROM_UNIXTIME(1545893190) 
ORDER BY created_at;
```

this should work

Comment: a DateTime field like f