# Error 1064 in Grafana for making a graph (using mysql database)

Tags: mysql, database, grafana

I am using Grafana (version 5.4.0) to visualize my data on my mysql database. I want to make a graph of my data. I have four columns: id , int1(has float as type), int2 (also float) and also date&time.

I would like to make a graph. On the x-axis the time and on the y-axis the value of int1. My tables name is data5.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    f AS "time",
    int1
FROM 
    data5
WHERE
    $__timeFilter(f)
ORDER BY 
    f
```

This is the error:

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'int1
>   FROM data5
>   WHERE
>     f BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1563793531) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(15' at line 3

I would be thankful for any kind of help.

[this is a picture of my Grafana dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsPNq.png)

[this is the picture of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2EnJ.png)

Comment: Looks like the issue is the second part of your filter is not complete  FROM_UNIXTIME(15' this should look more like the first part FROM_UNIXTIME(1563793531). It's not a valid UNIX timestamp and it doesn't have a closing paren. I would look into what is building $__timeFilter(f)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 1064 in Grafana for making a graph using mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57145848/error-1064-in-grafana-for-making-a-graph-using-mysql-database)